# How to click hotkey and simultaneously type a string?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, pynput

Click hotkey e.g. <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and simultaneously type a string and press enter. Should it be done in `on_press` method?

Code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')}
]
current = set()

def execute():
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position = (550, 80)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
    # keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.type('google.com')
    # keyboard.press(keyboard.Key.enter)
    # keyboard.release(keyboard.Key.enter)

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
    if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
        execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'pynput.keyboard' has no attribute 'type'

Answer (score 0):

Each `mouse` and `keyboard` has its own `Controller` instance, so you should import them separately. Something like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')}
]
current = set()

def execute():
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position = (550, 80)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
    keyboard_ctrl = keyboard.Controller()
    keyboard_ctrl.type('google.com')
    # keyboard_ctrl.press(keyboard.Key.enter)
    # keyboard_ctrl.release(keyboard.Key.enter)

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
    if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
        execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```